# Conclusions are not part of a question

Tags: discussion

After [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315314/difference-between-static-const-define-and-enum-in-performance-and-memo) has been solved, I added generalized conclusions at the end of original question, but they were [wiped out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21315314/revisions).

I understand that technically editor is correct, but what am I supposed to do?

Should I post my conclusions as another answer, accept it and take away reputation points from the main contributor to problem solving, whose answer is actually on-topic, though slightly narrower than my conclusions but with more details?

Comment: You can just do a rollback on the edit.

Comment: @LanceRoberts While in theory he could, in practice it would just lead to other people editing/flagging his question (especially since it's on Meta).  The accepted practice is to put answers in answers, and in the question.

Comment: Why do you think you'd be taking away reputation points from the main contributor?  Stack Overflow isn't a zero-sum game. I often will upvote multiple answers when I find them useful.  Also, if you're really worried about that, you can always edit the accepted answer and add your blurb, making sure to say that particular blurb is from you.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I meant rep for the accepted answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, make it an answer if it's an answer to your question. You don't necessarily have to accept the answer. You can leave that with your currently accepted answer if that did it for you. Unless your new answer improves upon it, in which case accepting it would not be unheard of.